# Transitioning from Winforms to WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

It had been many years since I have coded anything but I find myself working on a new project. I am an old Winforms guy any trying to transition to WPF. I am curious how some of my old vb.net code would work in WPF.

```
Public Sub mnuNav(fName As Form, intMnu As Integer, intCount As Integer, ctrlBtn As String, ctrlPnl As String)
        For int As Integer = 1 To intCount
            Dim btnName As Button = DirectCast(fName.Controls(ctrlBtn & int.ToString), Button)
            Dim pnlName As Panel = DirectCast(fName.Controls(ctrlPnl & int.ToString), Panel)
            If int = intMnu Then
                btnName.ForeColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
                btnName.Font = New Font(btnName.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                pnlName.Visible = True
            Else
                btnName.ForeColor = Color.Black
                btnName.Font = New Font(btnName.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
                pnlName.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

I have 7 textblocks in a grid and when you click one I want it loop through the textblocks, change the foreground color and also make it bold. How would I go about doing it?

Comment: Probably most of your WinForms code would not work in WPF, or should not work at least. If you're using WPF then you should be implementing the MVVM design pattern. In that case, changes you make in the UI will updated your view model via data-binding. The view model will then make any further modifications to itself that are required as a result of that change and then those changes will flow on to other aspects of the UI via data-binding to. You can use WPF like WinForms but you're wasting most of its power. Look into MVVM and start from the ground up.

Comment: WPF <> WinForms, you may want to check out XAML.

Comment: If you follow your old Winform approach with logic in code behind, then it should work in exactly same way, only you need to change properties of the controls. WPF controls have different properties than Winforms.